# What is so "direct" about the direct product?

Tags: terminology, universal-algebra

Let $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ be objects in some category of universal algebra. Then we may form what is called their "direct product"

$$
A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n
$$

with pointwise operations.

I've been wondering why we call this construct the "direct" product. Categorically, it seems to be one of the (canonically isomorphic) ways of constructing a product. What is so "direct" about it? After all, the diagram that the limit is over is devoid of arrows!

Comment: I am guessing that the word "direct" arises from the following facts: (1) there are many different products in certain categories; (2) the direct product is probably the "simplest (i.e., direct)" way to define a product.  Recall that for groups, you have semidirect, free, wreath, and direct products, and the direct product is the easiest to construct.

Comment: I think there were direct products long before there were direct limits.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming that it was somehow refering to "direction" or "directedness".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Are you also saying that the former term predates the latter?

Comment: Aha, so the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdirect_product was coined 1944.